# AJAX requests hang when served in quick succession

Tags: php, ajax, apache, http-get

On my laptop I have an app that makes 7 AJAX GET requests to a single PHP script at about the same time (millisecond difference). They all return successfully with the result I want.

Then I moved this script to a server (Windows Server) running Apache and PHP. However, this process hangs when I make the same 7 AJAX requests. However, if I make each request individually then they all come back successful! Something doesn't want me to do all 7.

Why is this happening? What configuration variables in the `PHP.ini` and `httpd.conf` can I look for to determine what this is?

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why send 7 requests at the same time ? Could you not group those into only one, which would return all the informations you need ? (The day you have lots of users, that would be much better for your server)

Comment: The request sent are highly dependent on the user and are random, I can not change this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem might be on the browser-side.

Most browsers have a 2 concurrent connections limit when talking to the same server.

When you moved your application to the server, the extra latency might have overlapped your AJAX requests, which on localhost were being served in quick succession.

You may want to check out these related articles:

- [The Dreaded 2 Connection Limit](http://cometdaily.com/2007/11/11/the-dreaded-2-connection-limit/)
- [The Two HTTP Connection Limit Issue](http://www.openajax.org/runtime/wiki/The_Two_HTTP_Connection_Limit_Issue)
- [Circumventing browser connection limits for fun and profit](http://www.ajaxperformance.com/2006/12/18/circumventing-browser-connection-limits-for-fun-and-profit/)

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of that. +1

Comment: Very interesting, I wasn't aware of this either!

Comment: It is also written in the HTTP spec, section 8.14 last paragraph: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html

Answer (score 1):

The server may have a throttler in place to keep excessive requests from coming in too quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your Apache configuration limits the number of concurrent connections from the same IP, or even Windows. What version of Windows is it? What kind of Apache installation, Standalone or as a part of XAMPP?

Comment: Laptop = Windows XP and the other machine = Windows Server 2003. Could it be because of the "KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the same client on the same connection." - or is this slightly different?

Comment: Laptop = WAMP and other Machine = Standalone (apache and PHP). PHP used as a module.

Comment: Sounds good, try fiddling with that. This would lead to the 7 connections being processed one after another, and not concurrently.